# Rails Sessions and SiteMinder/SSO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, single-sign-on, siteminder

I am integrating Rails with my company's SSO system.  I have the SiteMinder Apache module installed and enabled on my server.

The Rails application inspects the request object in a before_filter to determine whether the user has already been authenticated with SSO.  Upon finding the needed variable, my application then matches the user ID returned from SSO with a user account within itself, and authenticates that user (restful-authentication with ActiveRecord session store).

My problem is this: after successfully logging in using this method, after a few pages worth of clicking around I suddenly **lose** my Rails session and as a result am re-authenticated by my application (I go back to the homepage).

This is not a result of CSRF protection, as it:

1. Occurs in BOTH the Test and Production environments of my application (and it is turned off in the Test environment by default), and
2. Happens seemingly random regardless of request type: AJAX, GET, and POST requests have all led to this behavior.

Even if I *disable* the code that automatically logs the user in based on their SSO ID, and just hit the old login page on my application (after authenticating with SSO), I notice that every so often a new session id value in my browser cookie appears.

So the session is being reset when I have my Apache SSO module turned on.  Otherwise, all is fine and dandy.  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Rails sessions (like pretty much any web app session) are tracked by cookies. Even if you're using the AR session store, there's still a cookie with the sessionID, that's the only way a web app can keep track of sessions.  If the browser loses or deletes it's cookies, then it'll lose the session.

Alternately, if you have some Rails code that calls the #reset_session controller method. Or it might be possible to actually modify the #cookies hash yourself to remove the session identifying cookies (but you never want to).

From the information you give, I couldn't say what's causing the session to be lost. But these are where to start looking. If you can reproduce the problem, then take a look at your cookies , before and after the session gets 'lost'. You can look at cookies in your browser using it's own interface, or in the rails app (using a debugger, or even outputting to a page for debugging) from the hash returned by the #cookies method in a controller or view. When/how/why are they changing?

Sounds like you suspect the SSO module is deleting your rails-related cookies. That might be a question for SiteMinder support, and not a Rails issue.

Comment: I monitored the contents of my Rails session cookie in Firefox while repeatedly hitting the page.  The contents of the cookie **did** change, so at this point I'm wondering what causes Rails to decide to reset a cookie.  A different origination IP?  If the request looks "tampered with" (although I do not think the SSO module is tampering with the _contents_ of my Rails session cookie)?

Thank you for suggestion.  I've taken this question to the SiteMinder people and, well, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, etc to siteminder